# Jar not finding image

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

I have a maven project with spring-boot. I have a png image in *my-module/src/resources/images/image.png*.

I make `mvn clean package` and a Jar is generated, ok, now I run the Jar as `java -jar my_jar.jar` but I get this error **java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jose/projects/my-project/classpath:images/image.png**

In code I have:

`private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "classpath:images/image.png";`

and

`Image image = PngImage.getImage(IMAGE_PATH);`

Seems that it does not get `:classpath` keyword as it should, but as a literal.

When I unzip the Jar file the image is located in */BOOT-INF/classes/images/image.png*

The idea is not to change the code if possible but the way of execute or generate the Jar.
All suggestions are welcome though.

Thank you

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030109/1426227) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `PngImage` class you are using. But if the `getImage()` method accepts an `InputStream`, you can use:

```java
@Value("classpath:images/image.png")
private Resource resource;
```

And then:

```java
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

---

The following also should work:

```java
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("images/image.png");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```